# Use `mockall` crate for a trait with trait bounds

Tags: rust, mocking

I'd like to use `mockall` to generate a mock implementation for this trait:

```
#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
trait MyTrait {
    fn process<T: Read>(&self, data: T);
}
```

This leads to the compiler error:

> error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough

I could fix it by adding the `'static` lifetime to `T` as suggested by the compiler, but I don't want to do that. What is the best way to mock this trait without changing the function signature?

Answer (score 1):

[No](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/#generic-methods):

> ### Generic methods
>
> Generic methods can be mocked, too.  Effectively each generic method is an
> infinite set of regular methods, and each of those works just like any other
> regular method.  The expect_* method is generic, too, and usually must be
> called with a turbofish.  The only restrictions on mocking generic methods
> are that all generic parameters must be `'static`, and generic lifetime
> parameters are not allowed.
>
> ```rust
> #[automock]
> trait Foo {
>     fn foo<T: 'static>(&self, t: T) -> i32;
> }
>
> let mut mock = MockFoo::new();
> mock.expect_foo::<i16>()
>     .returning(|t| i32::from(t));
> mock.expect_foo::<i8>()
>     .returning(|t| -i32::from(t));
>
> assert_eq!(5, mock.foo(5i16));
> assert_eq!(-5, mock.foo(5i8));
> ```

Comment: So what's the best way to mock this trait then?